# encodeURIComponent() and UTF-8 when sending Form textarea via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, post, utf-8, encodeuricomponent

I am **sending data to a PHP backend file via AJAX** method POST. The data comes from a textarea, whose form has the next atribbute `accept-charset="UTF-8"`.
The AJAX function sends data as `http[act].send("title=" + encodeURIComponent(field.value)...)` and my PHP backend file begins with `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');`. Database ACCEPT NAMES and FIELDS are all set to UTF-8 (never had problems with this stuff).

I think I should decode in the PHP backend the `encodeURIComponent()` func. But how?

**Edit (sorry):**

**Fibra dietética** is inserted in DB as fibra **dietÃ©tica**
**Acompañada** is inserted as **AcompaÃ±ada**

...and so on.

Comment: why dont you use some framework to handle the AJAX? (if you do - what is it?)

Comment: jmm... I'm not gonna say I don't like frameworks, but i don't like using them for so simple things. I should work.

Comment: ajax is not simple in the native way (comparing to ajax using frameworks like jQuery)... without mentioning the fact that you have to deal with cross browser issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake. I was using `htmlentities()` *(PHP)* on the string before doing INSERT. A good alternative was using `strip_tags()` *(PHP)* to avoid "**HTML/Js/... injection**". Thanks to everyone for helping. i hope this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

peacemaker is right
in Ajax, use

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

then in php, use

```
rawurldecode()
```

Example
in Ajax

```
abc=encodeURIComponent(xxx)
```

then in php,

```
$varName = rawurldecode($_POST['abc'])
```

Answer (score 0):

use `rawurldecode($value)` see here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php

Comment: PHP.net says: 'Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character'. How can I conserve my plus symbols? Thanks! :)

Comment: when you get data that was sent encoded you dont need to decode it while taking it from the $_POST array

Comment: @YaronUliel Yes but... why do you think it does not get into the DB correctly? If I do a normal POST (no AJAX, NO encodeURIComponent) it works.

Comment: @Kenedy if you read the page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php there is a comment - someone wrote a function to deal with those characters

Comment: it can be many things, maybe the page isn't utf8 encoded (both file and content-type meta). maybe he didnt send `set names 'utf8'` query on that mysql connection.. and most probably - the ajax call doesnt have the right `content-type` header